# How to have an image appear in python/pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to learn to make a basic game using pygame. I want to import and display an image in .png format. so far my attempt has been:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
pygame.image.load('clouds.png')

white = (255, 64, 64)
w = 640
h = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
screen.fill((white))
running = 1

while running:
    screen.fill((white))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

The Image (clouds.png) is in the same folder as the file. when i try to run this i get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Enrique\Dropbox\gamez.py", line 3, in <module>
    pygame.image.load('clouds.png')
error: Couldn't open clouds.png
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the absolute path to the image?  Presumably: "C:\Users\Enrique\Dropbox\clouds.png"

Comment: Is your python build with png support?

Comment: Is your clouds.png named Clouds.png? / some capitalization problem?

Comment: where would i add the absolute path?

Comment: and no i have the file name correct

Comment: Also, your 'white' is mostly red.

Comment: Have you tried loading a bmp? If you can load a bmp but not a png, it would seem you don't have png support compiled in.

Comment: ill try that... and yeah i do know my white is really red(just fooling around with colors)

Comment: Okay. changing the image to .BMP causes no errors. now how do i get the image to display? The image is also 640 x 480 - after the program runs it displays the red color(named white)the goes not responsive

Comment: You need to set it to a variable, then call screen.blit() on it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go. It blits the image to 0,0. Your other problem is that your pyimage doesn't seem to be built with png support

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
img = pygame.image.load('clouds.bmp')

white = (255, 64, 64)
w = 640
h = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
screen.fill((white))
running = 1

while running:
    screen.fill((white))
    screen.blit(img,(0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: dont worry im sure ill have loads more questions tomorrow

Comment: Anytime. Also, here's a pretty good intro to pygame: http://pygame.org/docs/tut/intro/intro.html , and it should cover everything you do here - It is where I learned.

Comment: Note that you should usually call the [`convert`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) or `convert_alpha` method of the loaded image (pygame.Surface) because that will improve the performance tremendously, e.g. `img = pygame.image.load('clouds.bmp').convert()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an image handling block that I use in my games:

```
import os, sys
...
-snip-
...
def load_image(name, colorkey=None):
    fullname = os.path.join('images', name)
    try:
        image = pygame.image.load(fullname)
    except pygame.error, message:
        print 'Cannot load image:', name
        raise SystemExit, message
    image = image.convert()
    if colorkey is not None:
        if colorkey is -1:
            colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
        image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
    return image, image.get_rect()
```

You can copy-paste this in any game and it will work. `os` and `sys` need to be imported into your game or else it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

here you go, this is how I would do it.

```
import pygame as py # import pygame
py.init() # initialise it
img = py.image.load("clouds.png") # load the image
sc = py.display.set_mode((800, 600)) # create the screen
g = (0, 255, 0)
b = (0, 0, 0)
x = 350
y = 300
def render(x1, y1):
  sc.blit(img, (x1, y1)) 
running = True
while running:
    sc.fill(g) # fill the screen
    render(x, y) # BLIT IT ON
    key = py.key.get_pressed() # for keys
    # moving scripts start now
    for event in py.event.get():
      if event.type == py.KEYDOWN:
          if event.key==py.K_UP:
            y = y - 25
      if event.type == py.KEYDOWN:
          if event.key==py.K_DOWN:
            y = y + 25
      if event.type == py.KEYDOWN:
          if event.key==py.K_RIGHT:
            x = x + 25
      if event.type == py.KEYDOWN:
          if event.key==py.K_LEFT:
            x = x - 25
      if event.type == py.KEYDOWN:
          if event.key==py.K_l:
            print(py.event.get())
    mousex, mousey = py.mouse.get_pos()
    # mouse thing
    if py.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        x = mousex
        y = mousey
    py.display.flip()
```

*I hope this helps!*

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init(  )

screen = display.set_mode( ( 460 , 640 ) )

def picture( images , x , y , width , height , angle , horizontal_flip , vertical_flip ):

    images1 = image.load( images ) # loading image

    images2 = transform.scale( images1 , ( width , height ) ) # changing size

    images3 = transform.rotate( images2 , angle ) # changing angle 0 - 360 degree

    images4 = transform.flip( images3 , horizontal_flip , vertical_flip ) # horizontal or vertical flip - True or False

    images4rect = images4.get_rect(  )

    images4rect.x = x # setting x

    images4rect.y = y # setting y

    screen.blit( images4 , images4rect ) # image blit

while True:
    screen.fill( ( 0 , 0 , 0 ) )

    images = "image.png" # image name

    x = 100 # x-axis

    y = 100 # y-axis

    angle = 0 # 0 - 360

    horizontal_flip = False # True

    vertical_flip = False # True

    width = 200 # width of image

    height = 150 # height of image

    picture( images , x , y , width , height , angle , horizontal_flip , vertical_flip )

    pg.display.flip(  )
```

Comment: Hi, Do you want to add details and assumptions you have made in the program like the resolution should be 460x640, what is the path to the image, if the source image is of different resolution what happens etc., it would be more complete and would be a complete answer for people to understand and consume easily. Welcome to stack overflow.