# Pygame issues drawing

Tags: python, pygame, loading

I am new to Pygame, and in response to another question I asked on stackoverflow started to use it. Following the model  that was proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767129/how-to-have-an-image-appear-in-python-pygame), I wrote the following:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os, sys

white = (255, 255, 255)
img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('AHZ2000g4z.jpg'))
w = 640
h = 480

screen= pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
screen.fill((white))
running = 1

while running:
    screen.fill((white))
    screen.blit(img,(w, h))
    pygame.display.update()
    .....
```

The jpg exists in the current directory. pygame.image.get_extended() returns "true".

The programme compiles OK but simply draws a white rectangle. I would expect it to load the jpg into the surface ('rectangle'), but it doesn't. Any ideas?

FWIW I am running K/Ubuntu 14.04 with lightdm as the display manager.

thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are bliting your image at `(w,h)` which is draws the left top corner of the surface at the bottom right corner of the screen. This is why you cannot see the image. To fix this blit it at `(0,0)`.

```
screen.blit(img,(0, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks Bartlomiej. Silly. Sorted. Now all I have to do is deal with mousehandler - another part of the same problem!